# Do JWs have books besides the Bible that they view as "sacred" or "inspired"?

Tags: bible, jehovahs-witnesses

I see that the [JW website](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/binav/r1/lp-e) contains the text of a few different Bible translations: KJV, ASV, Byington, New World Translation and The Kingdom Interlinear Translation.

From articles such as "The Bible Really Is God’s Inspired Word" ([here](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/2010161)) I can see that their view is that Bible is inspired by God.

Do Jehovah's Witnesses have any other books, besides the Bible, that they view as "canon" (e.g. a separate/additional message from God) on the same level as (or higher than) the Bible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's only the Bible. A full description of how Jehovah's Witnesses determine whether a book is canonical can be found in the entry for ["Canon"](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1200000880) in the book, "Insight on the Scriptures, Vol. 1."

The only books accepted as inspired by God are the 66 books of the Bible commonly accepted by Protestants.